# VoltSecond equations for equivalent buck-boost of flyback

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Here is the equivalent buck-boost of flyback converter:

[image]

I proved the Volt-Second in a switch-on mode that agrees with the book result (n=22.86.)

[image]

In switch-off mode (regarding the above table):

$$t_{off}=(1-D)/f=2.94us$$
$$V_{off}=V_{diode}+V_{OR}=n*V_{D}+n*V_{o}$$

Where \$V_{o}=5V\$

Thus:

1. If I assume (as we assumed the switch has no drop voltage) \$V_{D}=0V)=>Voff=n*V_{o}=114.3\$ and
   \$Et=Voff*t_{off}=114.3*2.94us=336us\$ which is not equal to 473us.
2. If I assume \$V_{D}=1V=>Voff=n*V_{D}+n*V_{o}=22.86+114.3=137.16\$ and \$Et=Voff*t_{off}=137.16*2.94us=403us\$ which is not equal to 473us.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What makes this equivalent to a flyback? This looks like a perfectly ordinary inverting buck-boost converter to me.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. regarding the "switching power supplies a to z" book, we can substitute new voltage, current, and components values by reflecting the secondary circuit to the primary circuit by removing the storage transformer.

Comment: @JohnJin can you provide a reference for the images in the post?

Comment: Thank you, I found my problem is that the writer includes Vd in calculating the turn ratios and after that it ignores it. Here is the book: https://books.google.com/books?id=cuyyQ3N_8hIC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=13.5mm+to+530mils&source=bl&ots=sCpDC_REXe&sig=ACfU3U2xpzWfML9ivSYwICUJ7vKTz9rpMw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQnKCNycP3AhXGu6QKHXhKBIoQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At equilibrium or steady-state and in CCM operation, the dc transfer characteristic of the isolated buck-boost converter is \$V_{out}=V_{in}\frac{ND}{1-D}\$. From there, you can extract the operating duty ratio and determine the volt-seconds linked to the on- and off-time duration. At steady-state, they should be equal:

[image]

In the equation, \$N\$ characterizes the transformer turns ratio \$1:N\$ and, if made 1, you can determine the values for buck-boost converter since the flyback derives from this structure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. As I checked my equations with yours I see they are the same. In my example  \$E_{toff}=V_{off}*t_{on}= n*V_{out}*\frac{1-D}{F_{sw}}\$ where \$n=\frac{1}{n1}\$. But my answer is different ( As you can see my first "If" assumption)

Comment: These equations characterize the inductor volts-seconds balance and are actually used to determine the dc transfer characteristic of any converter: the average voltage across an inductor in steady-state is always 0 V.